# Shorthand for calling a method on an object in F#

Tags: f#

Is there a way to "generate" functions like this one:

```
fun x -> x.ToString
```

I would like to be able to turn an instance method into a static method which takes "this" as a parameter, like so:

```
items |> Seq.filter my_predicate |> Seq.map Object.ToString
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this has been discussed several times on the F# hub. See for example [instance methods as functions](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/3260.aspx). This is quite tricky problem, so there are no plans to have something like this in the first version of F# as far as I know, but it would be great to have something like that eventually :-).

Another workaround that you could do is to add static member as an extension method in F#:

```
type System.Object with
  static member ObjToString(o:obj) = o.ToString()

open System
[ 1 .. 10 ] |> Seq.map Object.ObjToString;;
```

But that is a bit ugly. Also, it seems that this works only if you use different name for the method. I guess that F# doesn't allow you to overload existing method with an extension method and always prefer the intrinsic one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I exactly understood you, but for this specific example you could write:

```
items |> Seq.filter my_predicate |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToString)
```

or

```
let f = fun x -> x.ToString
items |> Seq.filter my_predicate |> Seq.map f
```